# Nativescript-Vue: Handling emitted events in Frame

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a small Nativescript-Vue project in which I'm swapping out components inside the frame, like so:

HTML:

```
<StackLayout ~mainContent>
   <Frame id="mainframe">
      <Login @login-successful="onLoginSuccess"></Login>
   </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

I am able to catch the @login-successful event emitted by my Login component. Then I swap out the component using this code:

```
this.$navigateTo(HomePage, {frame: 'mainframe'})
```

HomePage component is successfully mounted. So far so good. But how do I dynamically attach another event listener to the component (similar to the @login-successful event) when I no longer have access to the markup to add an @ listener. I'm pretty sure it should be done with code, something along the lines of

(Pseudo-code)

```
MyComponent.$on('my-event', () => {})
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you asking about adding another listener to Login component? Can you explain the purpose of the event?

Comment: Nope, it would be adding a listener to the component which replaces the Login component. 

Flow is: Login > Successful > Emit success event from Login Component > Handle in parent App Controller > Dynamically swap out Login Component with User Component


What I now want to do is emit an event from User Component which will ALSO be handled by App Controller like login-success was. I realise I can't do this with an @-handler as I've dynamically altered the DOM, what is the accepted code way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you use a event bus, so you can always just import it from any component, fire event or listen to one.

Comment: Cool, yes I think that's a decent suggestion. Thanks!